# MSBuild error in Jenkins CI

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild

I have a weird error in Jenkins while doing an C# project build. I have a target specified in Jenkins which is the only target it needs to run. But in Jenkins console output I see the target has run without errors but then Jenkins is invoking MSBuild again and failing with a "No project or solution file error". I'm not sure why it's running MSBuild again after building the only target specified in the build parameters. This is what I have as build parameters in Jenkins:

```
/v:d /T:UpdateDLLs
```

Jenkins console output is as follows,

> Done building target "UpdateQuadraDLLs" in project "BatchBuild.xml".
>   Done Building Project "C:\Program
>   Files\Jenkins\workspace\Core3.0\Build\BatchBuild.xml" (UpdateDLLs
>   target(s)).
>
> Build succeeded.
>       0 Warning(s)
>       0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.39 Path To MSBuild.exe: msbuild.exe Executing
>   the command cmd.exe /C " msbuild.exe " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from
>   C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\Core3.0 [Core3.0] $ cmd.exe /C "
>   msbuild.exe " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% Microsoft (R) Build Engine
>   Version 3.5.30729.1 [Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3053]
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.
>
> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The
>   current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
>   Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild'
>   marked build as failure

Comment: It almost looks like you have a batch command specified somewhere else in your Jenkins build configuration. In the error message it specifically references a call to "cmd.exe /C msbuild.exe". This obviously wouldn't work because you're not specifying a project, which is exactly what the MSBuild output appears to say.

I almost hate to ask because it sounds too obvious, but can you check your build configuration to make sure you don't have an out-of-place command line call to MSBuild that shouldn't be there?

Comment: It really was an out of place msbuild invoke...upon further investigation i found that i had added another build event with nothing specified..thanks for pointing out...